# mywebsite.com/folder12 should display content to mywebsite.com?folder=12

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like `mysite.com?folder=12` to display content of `mywebsite.com/folder12`.

How do I accomplish that?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```